# Flutter Bloc with multiple relations with firebase query

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-bloc

so I have a firebase query where:
`user` document - has array of id's of `Spots`
`posts` collection - has multiple `post` documents and every post has single "spotId" 
`spots` collection - has multiple `spot` documents with unique id obvs

Now to display to User only Posts of Spots this user follows, I have to:
Iterate user "spots array" (the spots which he follows). Then for every `spot id` from this array I have to do a firebase query to `posts` collection where "spotId" == this id. So when I have only those Posts connected with Spot user is following I have to do another firebase query to `spots` collection to get this specific Spot data for Post display.

The method looks like this:

```
@override
  Stream<List<Future<Post>>> posts(List userFollowedSpots) {
    final listOfStreams = userFollowedSpots.map((id) {
      return postCollection
          .where("spotId", isEqualTo: id)
          .snapshots()
          .map((snapshot) {
        return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
          return spotCollection.document(doc.data["spotId"]).get().then((ds) {
            return Post.fromEntity(PostEntity.fromSnapshot(doc, ds));
          });
        }).toList();
      });
    });

    return StreamGroup.merge(listOfStreams); // <-- have to merge it as mapped userFollowedSpots returns Iterable<Stream...>>>>
  }
```

Then I'm using it like this:

```
Stream<PostsState> _mapLoadPostToState(LoadPosts event) async* {
    List<Post> allPosts = [];
    _postsSubscription?.cancel();
    if (event.userFollowedSpots != null && event.userFollowedSpots.length > 0) {
      _postsSubscription =
          _postRepository.posts(event.userFollowedSpots).listen((posts) {
        Future.wait(posts).then((waitedPosts) {

          if (allPosts.length > 0) {
            allPosts = allPosts + waitedPosts;
          } else {
            allPosts = waitedPosts;
          }
          add(PostUpdated(allPosts));
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

The question is: does it make sense? Because looks like a little hack. Normally I'm expecting one Stream from this `posts` method but here's a thing: When I'll be listen for this `post` method Steam, Firebase will be returning new `event` for every ID from id's array. So if array will be ["1", "2"] then the `Future.wait(posts).then((waitedPosts)` will return post for "1" and then for "2".

That's why I did this weird hack - I started to work with flutter_bloc, so can't tell if this is hack or acceptable solution?

Can anyone help with opinion?

Answer (score 3):

If you want all the result to be supplied together then you should use `Future.wait` method, which will change your `List<Future<Post>>` into `Future<List<Post>>`.

Comment: In that case, the Future.wait will resolve as much times are `userFollowedSpots` items has - I guess it's firebase snapshots specific. That's why I did this odd "imperative" trick with adding items to `List<Post> allPosts = [];`